# ¿Como reparar error al attach de SQL server? Capture de Pantalla

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hola anteriormente estaba instalado una version de **SQL server Express version 10.50.4000** he querido instalar **SQL server Enterprise 2008 R2 Full y descargue la version 10.0.1600** por eso desinstale la version **Express 10.50.4000** y hice lo siguiente para que estuviese actualizado primero instale **SQL server Enterprise 2008 R2 Full version 10.0.1600** y despues ensima instale **SQL server Express 10.50.4000** quise restaurar haciendo un attach en el SQL server pero ya no me decia que era error de version antigua hecha **10.50.4000** y que estaba en **10.0.1600** pero si me decia el siguiente error de version que el SQL server necesita algo de version **661** o superior y que tengo activa la version **655** pero no se como repararlo. por que no se a que se refiere exactamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que instalaste una version 2008 (10.0) en vez de una versión 2008 R2 (10.5). Puedes comprobarlo [aquí](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html).

La única opción es actualizar la instancia a una versión más actual. Si es para un ambiente de desarrollo, puedes descargar e instalar de forma gratuita la edición Developer creando una cuenta de [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/), sí es para algo productivo, las versiones más recientes de SQL Server permiten hasta 10GB por base de datos en [su edición Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) que es gratuita.